# How to fix index out of bounds exception when using chararrary

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am creating a wordle-type game for an intro to Java class, and keep encountering an index out of bounds exception on line 38, (shown with **), no matter what I seem to change. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
char[] letters = winner.toCharArray();
char[] getters = guess.toCharArray();
for (int q = 0; q < 6; q++){
    System.out.println("Please enter a 5 letter guess:");
        guess = in.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    **if (letters[i] == getters[i]){
        soFar = soFar + "||"+ getters[i] + "||";
    } else {
        soFar = soFar + getters[i];
```

Comment: Change `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){` to `for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(letters.length, getters.length); i++){`

Comment: At the time `getters` variable is created, `guess` doesn't have any value from your input. Therefore `getters` will be an empty array. The changes of `guess` doesn't affect `getters`'s value because they are two different objects. You should move your `getters` declaration line to under the first for loop

Comment: *"... no matter what I seem to change ... "*.  Changing things (randomly) in hope that that will fix the bug is not the way to fix a program.  What you actually need to do is to take a systematic, logical approach.  Understand what the exception means in the context, and then work backwards (logically) to what flaw in your code caused it.  Then figure out the correct way to fix the flaw.

Comment: Your for loop does not seem to have the closing brace. Are you sure the code even runs? MRE does not mean omitting out braces necessary for correct syntax. MRE means the shortest code, that I can copy paste into my IDE and reproduce the error, preferably without the need of any console I/O.

Answer (score 0):

From the available information of your post, let's assume your code would work something similar to function below -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String guess = "";
    char[] letters = "winner".toCharArray();
    char[] getters = guess.toCharArray();
    for (int q = 0; q < 6; q++){
        System.out.println("Please enter a 5 letter guess:");
            guess = "test";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        if (letters[i] == getters[i]){
            System.out.println(letters[i]);
        } 
    }
    }
}
```

The problem here is `char[] getters` is initialized to  whatever char array was backing the String `guess`. But later changing the `guess` String isn't going to assign the new reference to `char[] getters`. So when you are iterating over array you would then hit `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

If you are absolutely sure that `char[] letters  char[] getters`  will both be of size 6, then something like this would help -

```
guess = in.nextLine();
getters = guess.toCharArray();
```

So essentially -

```
char[] letters = winner.toCharArray();
char[] getters = guess.toCharArray();
for (int q = 0; q < 6; q++){
    System.out.println("Please enter a 5 letter guess:");
        guess = in.nextLine();
        getters = guess.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    if (letters[i] == getters[i]){
        soFar = soFar + "||"+ getters[i] + "||";
    } else {
        soFar = soFar + getters[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

An [IndexOutOfBondsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) appears whenever you try to access the empty or non-allocated index of any array (`char[]`, `int[]`, ...). Here is a great example for your case.

```java
// Your array contains 5 elements
char[] arr = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
// Then, you invoke an element that doesn't exist in an array
System.out.println(arr[5]); // This invoking will throw an IndexOutOfBondsException

// Even you invokes like this
System.out.println(arr[-1]); // Not exist
System.out.println(arr.size()); // Because the size is 5
```

Now staring at your code, it is a little bit ambiguous because the guess variable is an unknown type. Assume `guess` is a String and you are trying to put a `guess` as a String into a `getters`. Then you set a `guess` value as an inputted value. This thing is ambiguous and causes a wrong logic code and the `getters` still be an empty array (or not contain 6 elements).

**SOLUTION**
In order to solve it, you need to put the line `char[] getters = guess.toCharArray();` below `guess = in.nextLine();`. It means, that after taking a guess value from the user, you create an array that contains a guess character. Here is an instance of what I describe:

```java
char[] letters = winner.toCharArray();
// Take value from input
for (int q = 0; q < 6; q++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a 5 letter guess:");
    guess = in.nextLine();
}
        
// Then put it into a getters array
char[] getters = guess.toCharArray();
        
// Trying to compare
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (letters[i] == getters[i]) {
        soFar = soFar + "||" + getters[i] + "||";
    } else {
        soFar = soFar + getters[i];
    }
}
```